# Pi using USB audio problems with mp3 files

Tags: audio-playback

The pi chromium browser has a page that plays short audio files. Audio out is through USB speakers that work nicely, and pass the speaker-test -c2

Two MP3 files work perfectly. A third file produces no sound output to the USB speakers.

When I repeat this using an HDMI output (the monitor's speakers), all 3 files play perfectly.

How can I debug this?